# Shiv'a Ushloshim Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred thirty-seven?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Comment: Interesting cluster of relatively-significant ages, so far. Any idea if they're linked?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yishmael lived for 137 years (Genesis 25:17).

Amram, father of Moshe, lived for 137 years (Exodus 6:20).

Answer (score 5):

1. Avraham's age in the time of Akedat Yitzchak (and consequently - when Sarah died)
2. The Tehilim verse that is said before Birkat Hamazon every day that is not Shabbat or holiday

Answer (score 4):

Levi the son of Yaakov Avinu lived for 137 years. He was the longest living son of Yaakov.

Answer (score 4):

Yitzchak's age when Yaakov left Yeshivas Shem v'Ever

123 when he sent Yaakov away (derived from Megilla 17a)

14 years of Yaaakov learning